# Logging via sftp into a custom directory

Tags: sftp

I'm trying to set up a custom root directory (`/sftp/root`) for an SFTP user.
I have tried the two solutions I found around, but neither seems to work.

With the "default" `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
Match User sftpuser
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I logged (as expected) into the home directory.

```
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/sftpuser
```

First, I tried to define the `-d` option.

```
Match User sftpuser
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /sftp/root
```

But the outcome was the same.

```
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /home/sftpuser
```

Then, I tried the `ChrootDirectory`

```
Match User sftpuser
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /sftp/root
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

With the following permissions

```
ubuntuuser@inlab123:/$ ls -l
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root       4096 Jun 26 08:47 sftp

ubuntuuser@inlab123:/$ ls -l /sftp
total 4
drw-rw-rw- 2 sftpuser sftpuser 4096 Jun 26 09:16 root
```

But I got

```
Connection to 101.0.6.769 closed by remote host.
Connection closed
```

Finally, I tried

```
Match User sftpuser
    PasswordAuthentication yes
    ChrootDirectory /sftp
    X11Forwarding no
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    PermitTunnel no
    AllowAgentForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp -d /root
```

with the following outcome.

```
sftp> pwd
Remote working directory: /
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: `drw-rw-rw-` directories need the 'x' permission to access.